# rstudio does not use linux file manager

Tags: rstudio, file-manager

The last two versions of rstudio dows not utilize the operating system (in my case debian sid) file manager (Thunar in my case). Instead it uses a not so helpful window (see pic)

[image: HERE] to see the linux version of file manager in rstudio.

Is there a way to set Thunar as the default file manager?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tools -> Global Options -> General -> Advanced -> tick 'Use native file and message dialog boxes'

From [community.rstudio.com](https://community.rstudio.com/t/rstudio-does-not-use-linux-file-manager/162676/5)